# How to connect to an Oracle database from IntelliJ IDEA 14?

Tags: java, oracle, intellij-idea, database-connection

Could someone tell me exactly how could I manage this connection? I am doing this for like 3 days now and every example, every video on the net is about MySQL or SQLite connection with NetBeans. My goal is to put the results of a SELECT query in a JTable. Nothing more. I know I need some driver and connection URL, ResultSet, PreparedStatement, TableModel, but I didn't manage to find the perfect combination to get some results.

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain how your IDE is relevant to the question.  Surely, the Java code you will be developing would be the same no matter what IDE (or text editor) you used to write it ...

Comment: Because IntelliJ has a specific Database connecting system, as far as I know. The settings are different, more or less when you connect. (You connect your project to a database using a panel rather then writing code...)

Comment: Unless you are implementing code that runs *within* the IntelliJ IDE, then I think you are wrong about that.  Or maybe you are correct ... but it would be advisable NOT to use that feature of IntelliJ.  IMO it is a bad idea to tie your code to a specific IDE.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find a tutorial or video that covers all of this, then you need to combine sources that cover the individual parts of the problem.

For example:

- This covers configuring data sources in IntelliJ 14: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-a-db-data-source.html
- This covers JDBC database URLs for Oracle databases: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/urls.htm#BEIJFHHB.  And so does this: http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/Oracle-JDBC-Driver-Connection-URL.html
- The javadocs cover the various APIs you are using.
- and so on.

Comment: First link is a 404 now.

Comment: @Ben can you find where the document has moved to?

Comment: Not sure that it did, move. I was able to find this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/working-with-the-database-tool-window.html?origin=old_help&search=sql%20connection

Answer (score 1):

You may be struggling with all the options on the IntelliJ dialog. Most IDEs provide a way to specify the JDBC URL. If you are familiar with Oracle TNS names the below URLs will work for you when you have a complex Oracle address list (as in RAC, for instance) or when there is a firewall and you must specify `SERVER=DEDICATED`:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = yourdbhost.com)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
```

or

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = yourdbhost.com)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SID = XE)))
```

In most simple cases this will suffice:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@yourdbhost.com:1521:XE
```

Finally, make sure your username and password work by testing them with SQL/PLUS

Comment: where to get user/pass from if i just opened this bd for the first time?

Comment: @AlexNikonov There is no default password for Oracle XE. Ask the person who installed the database to tell you what they set the SYS and/or SYSTEM password to. They may also provide you with a custom user and password specifically for you or your application.